# Android app white screen blocked without errors

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles, blocked

I've set up my android app with a drawer navigation menu and after all the set up my app is just showing a white blank screen without launching my LAUNCHER activity and without doing nothing.

I know is quite obsolete but i can't figure out what's going wrong, also because i don't have any log errors.. i think is a problme of theming, i'll post some code below.

Thanks for the help.

This is what the app is showing:
[image]

**Theme.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.CAFTracker" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground" >@color/white</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>


    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarText" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CAFTracker">

    <activity
        android:name=".gui.activity.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

ActivityDefault.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/screen_default_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/screen_default_content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/screenToolbar"
            style="@style/toolbar"
            tools:context=".ToolBar" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen_default_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FrameLayout" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**Home Activity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Base {


public static Intent getHomeActivity(Context context){
    return new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.screen_default_container, HomeFragment.newInstance(), AppConfig.FRAGMENT_HOME)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected int getContentView() {
    return R.layout.activity_default;
}

@Override
protected int getTitleToolBar() {
    return R.string.homeSectionName;
}
```

}

**BaseActivity**

```
public abstract class Base extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Bind(R.id.navigationMenu)
NavigationView mNavigationView;

@Bind(R.id.screen_default_drawer_layout)
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Bind(R.id.screenToolbar)
protected Toolbar mToolBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    setContentView(getContentView());

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    CAFTrackerApplication.get(getApplicationContext()).inject(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mNavigationView != null) {
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        for (int menuItemPos = 0; menuItemPos < mNavigationView.getMenu().size(); menuItemPos++) {
            if (mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(menuItemPos).getItemId()
                    == Prefs.getIntPreference(getApplicationContext(), R.string.pref_ui_menu_selected)) {

                mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(menuItemPos).setChecked(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    loadInfoToolbar();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void loadInfoToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);

    try {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitleToolBar());

        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Logger.e("Support action bar is null");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ButterKnife.unbind(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

    Logger.i("Position clicked [ " + menuItem.getItemId() + " ]");

    Prefs.savePreference(getApplicationContext(), R.string.pref_ui_menu_selected, menuItem.getItemId());

    //Closing drawer on item click
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        // Sub Sections
        case R.id.nav_home:
            startActivity(HomeActivity.getHomeActivity(getApplicationContext()));
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}


protected abstract int getContentView();

protected abstract int getTitleToolBar();
}
```

Comment: Why do you not include HomeActivity?

Comment: Sure, i'll add HomeActivity and the BaseActivity! Here you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.screen_default_container, HomeFragment.newInstance(), AppConfig.FRAGMENT_HOME)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

to

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.screen_default_container, HomeFragment.newInstance(), AppConfig.FRAGMENT_HOME)
                .commit();
    }
}
```